# Do entities found in ndb queries count (for pricing) the same as get operations?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking at the per entity read pricing for Google Cloud https://cloud.google.com/datastore/pricing

Is it the same cost if the entity is found via query vs. direct get() by key?  Basically, is it cheaper to run queries to find the entity instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your linked documentation

> Projection queries that do not use the distinct on clause. This type of query is counted as a single entity read for the query itself. The individual results are counted as small operations.

> Keys-only queries. A keys-only query is counted as a single entity read for the query itself. The individual results are counted as small operations.

**Small operations are free**.

My interpretation (this is my own understanding which could be wrong) is - A direct get by key or projection query costs just a single read but a standard query will cost you a read for the query and a read for retrieving the result.

Comment: ok - thanks.  It looks like 1 for 1 read, unless it's a projection query.  A standard query read would be the same cost as a direct read by key.

Comment: I think a standard query read will cost more cos you have the query (1 read) plus fetching the result (another read) whereas a direct read by key is just 1 read.